# Confidence interval from two methods

Tags: confidence-interval, inverse-prediction

I have some data in the form of (x,y) tuples, 50 tuples. I am trying to fit a quadratic so

```
y = ax^2+bx+c
```

My goal is to find the max of the quadratic, so max = -b/2a and also find the confidence interval around that. I find the max after fitting the quadratic. For the confidence I chose two methods

1) Bootstrapping -> resampling a sample size equal to 50 again from the data with replacement, fit the quadratic and find the max, and compute the standard deviation of the estimated max

2) Fiellers's theorem ->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieller%27s_theorem

The two in general are close, but are drastically different when the errors are high and model fits are poor. Is that expected?

Secondly sometimes I do find that the confidence interval is like 15 for a max of 110, but the overall R_squared is negative, does that even make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence/question? Not sure what you mean

Comment: Sure, all I meant was that sometimes I do get a 95% confidence that is a not a very large number in comparison to the optimal value itself, but the R-squared itself is negative. This seems odd, In other words I was expecting to see a larger confidence interval.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. A confidence interval is a range of numbers, not a number. Do you mean the interval is _narrow_?

Comment: Yes I mean narrow vs wide.